# Is this bug or wrong code for PyQT4?

Tags: utf-8, pyqt4

I use PyQT4 for a long time. Yesterday I upgrade it to pyqt4-4.10.4. But for the first time, I started to get this error from that version. Here is my example code for the situation:

```
    #bla bla...

    self.testtext = QLineEdit()
    self.testbutton = QPushButton("Press It")
    self.testbutton.pressed.connect(self.testit)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.testtext,0,0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.testbutton,1,0)
    #...
def testit(self):
    print (self.testtext.text())

    #bla bla...
```

When I input "şşş" it prints the text "şşş" perfectly. But When I input "Müş", it prints "Mü_". I input "kır", it prints it correct. But when I input "çakır", it prints "çak1r".

So; 
şşş ---> şşş

Müş ---> Mü_

kır ---> kır

çakır --> çak1r

It's so interesting.

To sum up; i didn't get this bug when i was on previous PyQT version. The new version gives me this error.

Also; I use Python 3.3.5 and it's work with all unicode characters you know. But PyQt4 doesn't I think. So what's your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I removed 4.10.4 and installed 4.10.3 version and it solved this problem.

Update: I've got an email from riverbankcomputing.com, they write:
 *

> Try the current PyQt4 (and SIP) snapshots. There has been a fix for
>   Unicode conversions.

I have to look.